# Docker build ignore file permissions

Tags: docker

Im building my docker image from a jenkins job.

I do `ADD` an `index.html` file to the html directory of nignx.

The permissions on the jenkins host are

```
-rw-r----- 1 jenkins jenkins 3.3K Nov 10 14:12 index.html
```

and also the permissions inside the container are set to

```
-rw-r-----    1 root     root        3.2K Nov 10 13:12 index.html
```

so the webserver serves an `403 Forbidden` instead of the file.

Can I omit the permissions on the host and use a default umask (rwxr-xr-x) or do I have to chmod every file I want serve via nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Docker Documentation for ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add) states the following:

> All new files and directories are created with a UID and GID of 0.

This means that you have to run either `chown` or `chmod` after copying the files.

There are some further discussions here:

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7537
- https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9934

Comment: Ahh crap... Thank you for the realy good and informational answer.